# Traduction de « mean motion » et « time-mean »

Tags: traduction, anglais, terminologie, science, physique

Je veux traduire les mots « *mean motion* » et « *time-mean* » à partir d'[un article en Anglais](http://books.google.bi/books?id=iSgKLJtfluMC&pg=PA298&lpg=PA298&dq=Ovenden%20principle%20least%20action&source=bl&ots=7Jm1h7wq3C&sig=RWu5wOZZ3uKsISQV_GZfR3ggR2o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Vi9MUpLbE4SEhQfVp4DoAQ&ved=0CFIQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=Ovenden%20principle%20least%20action&f=false).
Mais Google me donne une traduction qui ne me paraît pas très scientifique.

Quelqu'un pourrait m'indiquer une traduction ?

Comment: The article is not available to me through google, is there another source available? In any case, could you please add a description of what these terms are supposed to mean in your question (pun not intended)? Does *mean* mean “average” like [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_motion)?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez The same thing happened to me but when I clicked on it the second time, it opened.

Comment: for me I reach it straight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La traduction pour "**mean motion**":

> Le mouvement moyen

On peut voir cela dans un contexte scientifique [dans cet article.](http://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00011585/en/)

La traduction pour "**time-mean**":

> Le temps moyen

Dans l'article, "time-mean" veut simplement dire "mean time".

Comment: Thanks @Patrick Sebatien. on the Google link, 298 page, I was feeling **mean motion ** could be said **vitesse moyenne** but I had to be sure( scientific correctness). searched for [moyen mouvement](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89quation_de_Kepler) and found it.